# Strange opacity transition issue only in Chrome and specific page context

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, transition, jquery-waypoints

I have an `<svg class="logo" ...>` element with the following CSS:

```
.logo {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in 0;
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome, and the CSS is made with SASS with [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) and its Neat grid.

I've set up a Waypoints function which triggers when an `h1` reaches the top:

```js
<script>
$('h1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    var logo = $(".logo");
    if (direction === "down") {
        logo.css("opacity", 1);
    } else if (direction === "up") {
        logo.css("opacity", 0);
    }
});
</script>
```

But the opacity is animated **only when scrolling up**. The thing is I wrote a [basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/2K2dC/3/) with similar elements (SVG logo, h1 title and some other content) and **it works just fine**.

I wonder if some library I'm using is interfering (besides Bourbon and Neat, just using regular jquery and waypoints, and prism.js for syntax highlighting).

Now I tested latest stable Firefox and Internet Explorer and the **original page works fine**, so it's kind of a bug of Chrome that only appears in the specific context of my entire page and not in the jsfiddle example I posted.

¿Any suggestions?

Comment: You realise the last `transition` property in your CSS isn't complete? Also, you should just use `.fadeTo()` instead of the CSS transitions.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in the question, the code is fine. I could just use fadeTo() but that doesn't fix the issue described.

Comment: Have you tried having a class added instead of changing the inline style ? Something in the line addClass("opaque") and a css .logo.opaque {opacity: 1;} (written like this so that it has more specifity)